# Retrieving data from Firebase database: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: xcode, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase database which looks like this:

[image: database]

I have no problem saving to the database but when I'm trying to retrieve data in the following way:

```
//Properties
@IBOutlet weak var bike1LBL: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var bike2LBL: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var bike3LBL: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var bike4LBL: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var chainLBL: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var brakeLBL: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var locationLBL: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var phoneLBL: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var ref = Firebase(url:"sdfghjkl/firebaseio.com/Order/")
    // Retrieve new posts as they are added to database
    ref.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in

        let road = snapshot.value.objectForKey("Bike-Type1") as? String
        self.bike1LBL.text = road
        let city = snapshot.value.objectForKey("Bike-Type2") as? String
        self.bike2LBL.text = city
        let mountain = snapshot.value.objectForKey("Bike-Type3") as? String
        self.bike3LBL.text = mountain
        let christiania = snapshot.value.objectForKey("Bike-Type4") as? String
        self.bike4LBL.text = christiania
        let chain = snapshot.value.objectForKey("Chain") as? String
        self.chainLBL.text = chain
        let brake = snapshot.value.objectForKey("Brake") as? String
        self.brakeLBL.text = brake
        let location = snapshot.value.objectForKey("Location") as? String
        self.locationLBL.text = location
        let phone = snapshot.value.objectForKey("Phone") as? String
        self.phoneLBL.text = phone
        print(snapshot.value)
    })
}
```

the app crashes and I get this error message, but that's all I got from the debugger:

[image: debug area - variables view/console]

Comment: From what you see, the properties that your code accesses seem to be there in the JSON. Did you step through the code in a debugger to see which `objectForKey()` is causing the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Frank van Puffelen! I've edited the post, I hope it provides more information now, but I still cannot figure out which key causes the crash.

Comment: There is an object that is a `NSArray` and not a `NSDictionary` as you think it is. It's hard to tell which one, you have to use breakpoints or at least printf to know which one may be the culprit. Please, avoid screenshot, and copy/paste the error message instead.

Comment: I've set breakpoints for every constant to which I'm assigning the value of a specific key, and this is what the debugging area looks like: snapshot FDataSnapshot! 0x00007fb50b470740,
self messengerApp.MainViewController 0x00007fb50b5c7960,
road String? Some,
city String? "" Some,
mountain String? Some,
christiania String? Some,
chain String? Some,
brake String? Some,
location String? unable to read data Some,
_core _StringCore 
_baseAddress COpaquePointer 0x000000000000ffff
_countAndFlags UInt 1
_owner AnyObject? nil None
phone String? Some,

Answer (score 0):

Will be better if you update to new Firebase 3.0 api and take a look to [MakinGIANTS - Post](http://blog.makingiants.com/firebase-database-chat-experience/) about firebase and queries (it's in Kotlin but "will look like" Swift) and may help

Answer (score 0):

From the [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write):

> You can use the FIRDataEventTypeValue event to read the data at a
>   given path, as it exists at the time of the event. This method is
>   triggered once when the listener is attached and again every time the
>   data, including any children, changes. **The event callback is passed a
>   snapshot containing all data at that location, including child data.**

So `snapshot` is actually an array of some of the objects in `Order`, not just the one most recently added. Try getting the last object and then grabbing the data from it:

```
ref.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
        let entry = (snapshot as! NSArray).lastObject as! NSDictionary
        let road = entry.objectForKey("Bike-Type1") as? String
        self.bike1LBL.text = road     
    })
```